# Why is Eclipse adding single quotes to my C command line parameters?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, command-line, quotes

I'm running Eclipse v4.6 (Neon1) RC1 on a Windows & nbsp;10 machine, and it seems to be adding single quotes around *each* command line argument/parameter that I pass during debug. I see this show up in memory for each `argv`.

Strangely I can't produce these quotes to the console with a printf (during RUN); the program successfully loads the file specified by the parameters and outputs to console.

The command line arguments are set in the application run config->Parameters tab, as (single line, no quotes added):

```
keyFile.txt inputFile.txt outputFile.txt
```

I do not see this behavior in NetBeans (in fact have switched temporarily).

The issue is this appears to be causing problems with `fopen` when debugging: it can't find the file. I assume both are using the same working directory, because if I use a static filename of "keyFile.txt", debug works OK.

Unfortunately my console output doesn't work in debug, so I'm a little limited at the moment.

The example code is a much trimmed down version, to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Arguments: keyfile.txt inputfile.txt outputfile.txt

    char * firstArg = argv[1];
    char * secArg   = argv[2];   // Leaving these to show quotes on other inputs as well
    char * thirdArg = argv[3];

    printf("First arg:\t%s\n", firstArg);
    printf("Ptr Address, uint cast:\t0x%x\n", (unsigned int) firstArg);
    printf("Ptr Address, void* cast:\t%p\n", (void *) firstArg);
    printf("Char at Ptr:\t%c\n\n", (char) *(firstArg));

    printf("Second arg: \t%s\n", secArg);
    printf("Third arg: \t%s\n", thirdArg);

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(firstArg, "rb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
     {
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
     }

    int kLength=0;
    int inputChar;
    unsigned char keyin[256];

    printf("\nData from file:\n");
    while ((inputChar = fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)        // Read KEYFILE
    {
        if ((kLength%8)==0) { printf("\n"); }
        keyin[kLength++] = (unsigned char) inputChar;
        printf("0x%x\t",inputChar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On Run, output is as expected/follows:

```
First arg:    keyFile.txt
Ptr Address, uint cast:        0x6b1748
Ptr Address, void* cast:    006B1748
Char at Ptr:    k

Second arg:     inputFile.txt
Third arg:     outputfile.txt
current Path: C:\Users\***\Google Drive\***\eclipse workspace\argTest
Data from file:

0x59    0x45    0xba    0x1e...
...
(data I expect is displayed from file ...)
```

But during debug, I get trapped by a null fptr, and I see the quotes in memory:

Debug memory: firstArg points to 0x6E1760:
[image: Debug memory: firstArg points to 0x6E1760]

Looking at the gdb traces, I see the single quotes here as well. Shown below is everything leading up to this point:

```
311,234 2-gdb-version
311,239 ~"GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1\n"
311,240 ~"Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
311,240 ~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is fre\
e software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitt\
ed by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
311,240 ~"This GDB was configured as \"mingw32\".\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
311,240 ~"<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
311,240 2^done
311,241 (gdb)
311,243 3-environment-cd "C:/Users/***/Google Drive/***/workspace/argTest"\
311,250 3^done
311,250 (gdb)
311,251 4-gdb-set breakpoint pending on
311,260 4^done
311,260 (gdb)
311,261 5-gdb-set detach-on-fork on
311,270 5^done
311,270 (gdb)
311,271 6-enable-pretty-printing
311,280 6^done
311,280 (gdb)
311,281 7-gdb-set python print-stack none
311,290 7^done
311,290 (gdb)
311,291 8-gdb-set print object on
311,300 8^done
311,300 (gdb)
311,301 9-gdb-set print sevenbit-strings on
311,310 9^done
311,310 (gdb)
311,311 10-gdb-set host-charset UTF-8
311,320 10^done
311,320 (gdb)
311,321 11-gdb-set target-charset WINDOWS-1252
311,330 11^done
311,330 (gdb)
311,331 12-gdb-set target-wide-charset UTF-16
311,340 12^done
311,340 (gdb)
311,342 13source .gdbinit
311,350 &"source .gdbinit\n"
311,350 &".gdbinit: No such file or directory.\n"
311,350 13^error,msg=".gdbinit: No such file or directory."
311,350 (gdb)
311,351 14-gdb-set target-async off
311,360 14^done
311,360 (gdb)
311,361 15-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
311,370 15^done
311,370 (gdb)
311,379 16-file-exec-and-symbols --thread-group i1 Debug/argTest.exe
311,384 16^done
311,384 (gdb)
311,385 17-gdb-set --thread-group i1 args 'keyFile.txt' 'inputFile.txt' 'outputFile.txt'
311,394 17^done
311,394 (gdb)
...
```

Comment: The obvious question first: did you double (triple) check that you didn't add these quotation marks yourself?

Comment: Next the more important question: So when running in debug, the printf does *not* show the quotation marks? Can you put a second printf (printing the steering) behind these three printf statements? Does *that* include the quotation marks?

Comment: Then: main returns an int.

Comment: Try changing `printf("Ptr Address:\t0x%x\n", (int) firstArg);` to `printf("Ptr Address:\t%p\n", (void *) firstArg);` does that change the behaviour?

Comment: Oh, and `%x` expects an **unsigned** int.

Comment: this line: `printf("Char at Ptr:\t0x%x\n\n", (int) *(firstArg));` is casting the first item at the address referenced by `firstArg` as an integer, but what you really want is a character.  Suggest: `printf( "Char at Ptr: \t%c\n\n". (char) *firstArg );`

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  Always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.   We are not here to debug an `eclipse` anomaly from code that does not cleanly compile.   And what is the command line? where is the error occurring?

Comment: Guys/Gals - thank  you very much for the responses, sorry I didn't see them right away and apologies for the crude code (it's been a while). Will try to address your comments this evening.

Comment: Daniel - yes I confirmed that I did not add the quotes myself. I'm specifying them in the application run configuration, Arguments tab, all on a single line, each separated by a space. I'm not immediately sure where to find it, but I will check the run and debug commands that are being executed by eclipse.

 As for running in debug, my console out does not function in debug mode (it's maddening, and I haven't figured out why yet), so I'm flying a bit blind while in debug.

Comment: I have added gdb trace info, if that helps. Also assured the pointer address is being showed correctly.

Comment: The windows standard is that the command line argument is a single string, it is up to the CRT *not* the shell to parse it into the arguments for main. The windows convention is single quotes have no special meaning, it looks like Eclipse is assuming Linux and quoting for the shell. 1) As a workaround, try adding double-quotes around the arguments yourself. This may possibly prevent this behaviour.  2) Check the commandline arguments using Task manager details tab (optional column) to see what was actually passed to the process.

Comment: 3) Try OutputDebugString since you are on windows. Debugger should get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Eclipse, tracked here:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494246

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ben. I saw reference to a similar bug in my searching, but it was from long ago and I didn't expect such an issue to be present in a mainstream ide.....

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is to set the arguments in .gdbinit file instead of setting in Arguments tab (in Debug Configurations), just put the line like:

> set args arg1 arg2

And then, it works fine!